# Match word within [[ ]]

Tags: c#, regex

In C#, I want to use a regular expression to match words within [[XXX]].

ex;

> Vennligst betal følgende faktura: Fakturanr: [[INVOICENO]], Beløp:
>   [[AMOUNT]], Forfall: [[DUEDATE]], KID: [[KID]] til konto:
>   [[GYMACCOUNT]]. Mvh Aktiv365

Comment: did you actually try to look it up?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question sort of reads as a set of requirements. Any code to show? What research have you done? These things will help us help you.  Good luck!   _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match the word inside square brackets.

```
(?<=\[\[)\w+(?=]])
```

- `\w+` one or more [word characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)
- `(?<=\[\[)` if preceded by `[[`
- `(?=]])` if followed by `]]`

[See demo at regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5C%5B%5C%5B)%5Cw%2B(%3F%3D%5D%5D)&i=Vennligst%20betal%20f%C3%B8lgende%20faktura%3A%20Fakturanr%3A%20%5B%5BINVOICENO%5D%5D%2C%20Bel%C3%B8p%3A%20%5B%5BAMOUNT%5D%5D%2C%20Forfall%3A%20%5B%5BDUEDATE%5D%5D%2C%20KID%3A%20%5B%5BKID%5D%5D%20til%20konto%3A%20%5B%5BGYMACCOUNT%5D%5D.%20Mvh%20Aktiv365)

Answer (score 0):

try

Use escape character in regex :

```
 \[\[xxx\]\] in regex
```

Comment: not work.. thanks for the try..

Answer (score 0):

You can try the https://regex101.com/

and May be this expression do

```
\[\[.*\]\]
```

Comment: Not work... 
give [[INVOICENO]], Beløp: [[AMOUNT]], Forfall: [[DUEDATE]], KID: [[KID]] til konto: [[GYMACCOUNT]]

Comment: but i want list,

INVOICENO
AMOUNT
DUEDATE
KID

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern.

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\[\[.+?]]");

var matches = r.Matches(input);
```

Comment: it works... thanks Akhgary.